# Expression : À qui de droit

Tags: traduction, anglais, correspondance

En anglais on peut utiliser l'expression (pour des lettres de motivation, des lettres de recommandation, etc.)

> To who(m) it may concern,

Je me demande si l'expression française

> À qui de droit,

peut s'employer (dans le même contexte) ou la formule passe-partout

> Madame, Monsieur

est plus adéquate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J'éviterais d'utiliser « *à qui de droit* », en particulier au début d'une lettre car c'est une expression très (trop) juridique.

Il vaut mieux commencer ce type de document en décrivant d'une manière ou d'une autre les personnes à qui la suite est destinée, du moins si elles ont une caractéristique identifiable. Par exemple :

> - À l'attention des parents d'élèves,
> - À tous les Français,

Si le document n'est pas très important, on peut aussi commencer par :

> - Aux personnes intéressées,

Pour une lettre de motivation, la norme est :

> - Madame, Monsieur,

Answer (score -3):

J'ai toujours utilisé « *À qui cela concerne* ». Personne ne m'a jamais dit que c'était mal.

Comment: Personne n'a osé, peut-être... Toujours est-il que cette formule n'est pas du tout idiomatique (en France).

Comment: Il y a un _flag_ pour suppression, mais voir la réponse avec le vote me semble davantage utile que le serait son absence ? Par ailleurs bienvenue sur le site !